# Create subscription for Inbox folder's subfolders and How do we perform Subscription for multiple folders in one request similar to EWS

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

With reference to the GRAPH API mentioned at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=objc:

1. How can I subscribe for new message notifications to Inbox's subfolder.(Let's say that I have a testFolder as subfolder inside Inbox.
2. With EWS, I can specify all folder IDs for which I want to subscribe for new message Notifications in single request. Is there a way to achieve the same with Graph API i.e. subscribing for new messages in multiple folders in single request by passing all folders ids/names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subscribe to each folder separately, the notifications do not bubble up to the parent folder.

To subscribe to the subfolder, the resource value should be something like:
users/{a}/mailFolders/{b}/childFolders/{c}/messages

Where a is the id or email of the user, b the is of the main folder and c the id of the subfolder

Comment: Thanks much. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Current state: the folder id is optional. You can use {userid}/messages resource in subscription. I have just tried it and it does work. Your notification URL will be called whenever any changes occure in any folder regarding a mail message. This is a quotation from MS documentation: me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages, me/messages. Please check MS docs here: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)